# SAP WebIDE Uncaught ReferenceError: oView is not defined

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use the Geolocation Cordova Plugin in SAP WebIDE. The Cordova Plugin works perfectly, I can get the lat and long info. The problem is with this line  which give me the error: oView is not defined.

```
oView.byId("txtLatitude").setText(position.coords.latitude);
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: oView is not defined

In XML view I got the txtLatitude id set, so no issue with XML view.

This is the code of controller:

```
 sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("GPS.GPS.controller.GPS", {
        oView: null,
        onInit: function() {
            var oView = this.getView();

        },

        getPosition: function() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onGeoSuccess, this.onGeoError, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            });
        },

        onGeoSuccess: function(position) {
            oView.byId("txtLatitude").setText(position.coords.latitude); <<--This line got error: undefined
        },


        onGeoError: function() {
            console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        },      
    });
});
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: you can directly use 
this.getView().byId("txtLatitude")....    ??

Comment: I tried, not working too. I guess because of callback from Geolocation plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your function scope inside `onGeoSuccess`, as it is a callback (that is why `this.getView()` does not work).

One way to handle this, is to use [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onGeoSuccess.bind(this), ...
```

Then you can use `this.getView()...` inside `onGeoSuccess`.